# How to pass form parameter in ajax post?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, post

I have an ajax post , where in I pass a parameter `btnRole` as `continue` like this :

```
$("form.myForm input[name='btnRole']").val('continue');
```

I tried to pass another parameter here :

```
$("form.myForm input[name='myDevice']").val('android');
```

But , when i try to get the `myDevice` in java like this :

```
System.out.println("query String ::"+request.getParameter("myDevice"));
```

I get `null` as the `sysout`.

Can some one tell me what am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: And what does the 'btnRole' parameter has? Are you sure your form has all other values and just not this one?

Comment: `btnRole` also does not contain any value, i just checked. So just wanted to know is there any way of sending a parameter like that as i mentioned in ajax ?

Comment: are you submitting the form? If so, how? We will need more code as to how you're submitting the form via Ajax and how you're unmarshalling the form in the server side.

Comment: Do you have actual inputs in the form with those names?